# Как обезопасить запуск приложения?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, консоль

Подскажите, каким способом можно обезопасить запуск приложения, если оно использует консольные команды и аргументы, через планировщик заданий.

Если приложение может установить свои параметры, то оно может и отключить свои параметры. В плохих руках это приведет к отключению важных функций прописанных в приложении.

Несколько вариантов:

- создавать файл в определенной папке, и при отсутствии этого файла, запрещать запуск приложения
- создавать ключ реестра, и при отсутствии этого ключа, запрещать запуск приложения

Comment: Никак, при желании эта защита легко ломается

Comment: Что насчет CAPTCHA

Comment: Куда вы будете выводить капчу? Я вас не понимаю

Comment: Можно ведь использовать функции консоли но при этом использовать `winforms`, пользователь допустим вводит каптчу (один раз), эти действия сохраняются и в дальнейшем, приложение будет работать на ПК этого пользователя.

Comment: Какой в этом смысл? Если я получу ваше приложение и у меня будет цель его взломать, то я найду в коде проверки и отключу их. Никакими ухищрениями вы этого не отмените

Comment: Чтобы приложение само у себя не отключало установленные функции нужно защитить доступ к его запуску. То есть, если кто-то возьмет приложение и будет запускать его на другом ПК, то все функции приложения смогут отключить. Как вирус, только когда приложение само себя отключает, в плохих руках.

Comment: @Vitokhv, вам несколько раз сказали что это легко сломать. Чтобы вы не сделали, какое бы извращённое условие, один мой JMP в нужном месте, и ваша программа послушно выполнит всё что должна.

Comment: Единственное, что вы способны сделать - поставить какой нибудь обфускатор, чтобы увеличить время, необходимое мне для того чтобы найти куда именно лучше всего сделать прыжок. Но, опять же, это всего лишь время, программу вы не защитите.

Comment: Кстати, если вдаваться в вирусологию, проблемы борьбы с виртуализацией, от части, решают вашу задачу, но, для этого нужен опыт. Если коротко, суть решения проблемы заключается в генерации ключа доступа, который подаётся в каждую функцию вашей программы, и на основании которого выполняется каждое действие. Обходить каждый подобный ключ - весьма затратно, и взломщику нужна будет огромная мотивация. Если такая мотивация имеется, то вашу программу не способно защитить ничего из известных способов...